# How to create a spreadsheet file with the google drive API, and set the default tab title to something other than "Sheet1"

Tags: node.js, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I want to create a spreadsheet via the google drive(v3) API where:

1. I upload a CSV of data to populate the first tab
2. I am able to set
   the name of the tab to something other than "Sheet1"

I spent all night crawling the google API for sheets(v4) and drive(v3), but still can't figure this one out!

If I can't do it this way, it seems like I will have to send an additional request to update the sheet properties to change the title after I do the initial upload. I'd like to avoid that if possible, but I realize it might be the only way.

Here's the API request I'm sending:

```
let fileMetadata = {
  name: name,
  title: 'rawData', //This does NOT get set! Tab appears as "Sheet1"
  mimeType: 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'
}

let media = {
  mimeType: 'text/csv',
  body: data // The body data is the raw parsed CSV
}

var Google = google.drive('v3')
Google.files.create({
  auth: auth,
  media: media,
  resource: fileMetadata
}, function(err, response) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err)
    return done(err)
  } else {

    console.log('success!')
    console.log(response)

  }

})
```

Comment: The answer over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63628535/246801) allows you to create the CSV as a Sheet. The trick I needed was setting the File's mimeType as   Google Sheet (...vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet) **and also** setting the mimeType/contentType on the media itself. I see you did that, not sure why it didn't work (other than in the intervening 6 yrs something changed for the better).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I try creating a new spreadsheet using [Sheet API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/), then use Method: [**`spreadsheets.create`**](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/create). Using the Specific API like Sheets API gives you more of specialize method like adding properties of Sheet Title (for more sheets specific methods).

> Creates a spreadsheet, returning the newly created spreadsheet.

```
// BEFORE RUNNING:
// ---------------
// 1. If not already done, enable the Google Sheets API
//    and check the quota for your project at
//    https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/sheets
// 2. Install the Node.js client library by running
//    `npm install googleapis --save`

var google = require('googleapis');
var sheets = google.sheets('v4');

authorize(function(authClient) {
  var request = {
    resource: {
      // TODO: Add desired properties to the request body.
    },

    auth: authClient
  };

  sheets.spreadsheets.create(request, function(err, response) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return;
    }

    // TODO: Change code below to process the `response` object:
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
  });
});

function authorize(callback) {
  // TODO: Change placeholder below to generate authentication credentials. See
  // https://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/nodejs#step_3_set_up_the_sample
  //
  // Authorize using one of the following scopes:
  //   'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
  //   'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'
  var authClient = null;

  if (authClient == null) {
    console.log('authentication failed');
    return;
  }
  callback(authClient);
}
```

I used the Try this API
[image]

Resulting to:

[image]

This will also be in your Google Drive.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ah cool thanks! For some reason I was under the impression you could only create files via the drive API, and then later manipulate them via spreadsheets and spreadsheets.values

Comment: @DirtyBirdNJ I am trying to copy entire sheets from one spreadsheet to new created spreadsheet https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50679329/how-to-copy-entire-sheets-from-google-spreadsheet-in-nodes