# google drive api v3 create csv or spreadsheet using service account in node js

Tags: api, csv, spreadsheet, drive

I am using node with angular and I need to create the an API to create spreadsheet file on google drive with it's V3 API.
After creating the file we need to give permission for access in google drive, the following link is about grant permissions:
[Grant permission to an existing file on google drive api v3 in node js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63630143/grant-permission-to-an-existing-file-on-google-drive-api-v3-in-node-js/63630144#63630144)

Answer (score 1):

```
const google = require("googleapis").google;
const credentials = require('path to your service account file credentials.json');

async function uploadCsvFile(filename, content, callback) {
    const client = await google.auth.getClient({
        credentials,
        scopes: ["YOUR SCOPES"]
    });
    const drive = google.drive({ version: 'v3', auth: client });
    drive.files.create({
        resource: {
            name: filename,
            mimeType: 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet',
            convert: true,
        },
        media: {
            mimeType: 'text/csv',
            body: content,
        },
        fields: 'id, webViewLink'
    }, function (err, res) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        const files = res;
        if (files) {
            callback(files.data);
        } else {
            console.log('No files found.');
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Setting the mimeType on the file/resource object as a Google Sheet **and** setting the content-type/mimetype on the media itself as a CSV was the trick I needed.