# Grant permission to an existing file on google drive api v3 in node js

Tags: node.js, csv, google-drive-api

After Creating a csv file or spreadsheet by google drive api v3 we need to give permission to make that file visible in google drive.

Answer (score 1):

```
const google = require("googleapis").google;
const credentials = require('path to your service account file credentials.json');
const async = require("async");

async function filePermission(fileId, callback) {
    const client = await google.auth.getClient({
        credentials,
        scopes: ["YOUR SCOPES"]
    });
    var permissions = [{ 'type': 'user', 'role': 'writer', 'emailAddress': 'test@example.com' }];
    const drive = google.drive({ version: 'v3', auth: client });
    async.eachSeries(permissions, function (permission) {
        drive.permissions.create({
            resource: permission,
            fileId: fileId,
            fields: 'id',
            sendNotificationEmail: false,
        }, function (err, resp) {
            if (err) return console.log(err);
            callback(resp);
        });
    }, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
        } else {
            console.error("Permissions Granted");
        }
    });
}
```